# Adding TabGestureRecognizer to TextField

Tags: swift, uitextfield

All my UiTextFields are created  programmatically so i can't just right-click-pull-over the onTab function to the swift file.

I tried to add a gesture recognizer to the text field, but now I have to DOUBLE-click so clickTextField() is triggered.

```
// make clickable
let clickName = MyTapGesture(target: self, action: #selector(ViewMain.clickTextField(_:)))
clickName.count_of_selection = String(i)
self.finishName[i].addGestureRecognizer(clickName)
```

How can I make it so that this works with one click. A different approach maybe?

Answer (score 1):

`UITextField` has a tap gesture. You need to use it's delegate methods:

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField)
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField)
func textFieldShouldEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField)
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField)
func textFielShouldClear(_ textField: UITextField)
func textFielShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField)
```

Do not forget

```
yourTextField.delegate = self
```

after you create an extension for you vc:

```
extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    // here you add the necessary delegate methods for your textFields
}
```

Note: You do not need to implement every method. Use only the one you need. More details can be found on [AppleDeleveloper](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfield) .

Answer (score 0):

try setting a tag value to each UITextField to be able to deferenciate between them.
For example :

```
var iter = 0 //Defaults auto-incrementation                                        

let textField = UITextField()
textField.frame =  CGRect(x: 20, y: y, width: Int(UIScreen.main.bounds.width-40), height:50)
textField.placeholder = title + " :"

//Setting the tag            
textField.tag = iter

//Setting the controller as delegate to UITextField
textField.delegate = self

 //AddSubview
 self.view.addSubview(textField)

 //Auto-incrementation
 iter += 1
```

You need also to make use of UITextField delegate methods :

```
//TODO: Declare textFieldDidBeginEdditing here :
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ activeTextField: UITextField) {
                 //Code
}
//TODO: Declare textFieldDidEndEditing here :
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ activeTextField: UITextField) {
                 //Code
}
```

it depends on your needs you can use more or less methods. Good Luck.